# Number of connected componnents

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, connectedness, group-actions, isometry

Let $G$ be a finite group of isometries of a Riemannian manifold $\overline{M}$ acting properly discontinuously. Let $\pi : \overline{M} \to \overline{M}/G$ denote the projection onto the quotient. **If $M$ is a connected hypersurface of the quotient, is it true that the number of connected components of $\pi^{-1}(M)$ is a divisor of the order of $G$?**

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem.  ("Stabilizer" here means "lands in the initial connected component".)

Comment: You mean pick a point in one connected component and apply the theorem to the orbit and stabilizer of this point?

Comment: @EduardoLonga : Yes.

Comment: But $G$ also acts on the set of components, right?

Comment: @EduardoLonga : Yes.  "Being in the same connected component" is an equivalence relation on the set of points.  You are free to investigate the group acting on the points or to investigate the induced action on the components.  But pick one.

Comment: The action is transitive?

Comment: @EduardoLonga : Why would it be?  If I have more than one connected component and a trivial group, the action has no hope of being transitive.

Comment: But if you have a trivial group, the inverse image of $M$ has precisely one connected component, @EricTowers .

Comment: @EduardoLonga : Ah, yes.  Forgot the details of this problem.  Perhaps further progress would be made if you were to augment your question with what progress you have (and have not) made.